# Как вернуть массив из функции в PHP?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть функция `parseDesc()`. В результате ее выполнения получается массив `$productDesc[]`.

Вопрос: Как вытащить этот массив и использовать не только в самой функции?

Answer (score 7):

Чтобы вернуть результат работы функции, необходимо использовать оператор [`return`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.return.php).

После этого можно будет присвоить результат работы функции переменной.

Пример:

```
function parseDesc() {
    return [];
}
$productDesc = parseDesc();
```

Answer (score 1):

Уважаемый @Egor Smolyakov На ваш вопрос ответил @Ипатьев и это половина ответа. Этот ответ абсолютно верен, если результат вашей функции это генерировать массив `$productDesc` Но если у вас функция выполняет другую задачу, а генерация массива побочное действие, то вам скорее всего придется изменять формат выводимых данных

Пример
было

```
function parseDesc() {
    return $result;
}
```

Стало

```
function parseDesc() {
   return ['result'=>$result,'arr'=>$productDesc];
}
$productDesc = parseDesc();
$productDesc = productDesc['arr'];
```

Либо использовать ссылку в функции, что чревато ошибками при повторном вызове функции

```
$productDesc=[]
function parseDesc() {
   &$productDesc=$a;
   return $result;
}
```

Но я на стадии проектировании выбираю - либо это функция выполняющая конкретно возложенное на нее обязательство, либо сущность с характерными для нее свойствами

Пример

```
class ParseDesc{
  protected $product_desc=[];
  public function doParse(){
    $this->product_desc=$a;
    return $result;
  }
  public function getProductDesc(){
    return $this->product_desc;
  }
}
```

Применение

```
$obj= new ParseDesc();
$parser_result=$obj->doParse();
$productDesc=$obj->getProductDesc();
```